# Remove dependencies from yarn.lock

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

After editing package.json manually (i changed the source url for a dependency) in the yarn.lock an entry was added with the new url but the old one was kept. 
It tried to syncronice it using

```
yarn install
```

Old entries keep being there
Also tried removing them using

```
yarn remove dependency-name
```

It was removed from the package.json but not from the yarn.lock.

I'm afraid that when i run the yarn install in a new environment it tries to pull the old dependencies found in yarn.lock and i've read that it's not recommended to edit yarn.lock manually.

How can i get rid of that old dependency entries that remain in yarn.lock without editing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean up your `yarn.lock` file with the [yarn-deduplicate](https://github.com/atlassian/yarn-deduplicate) tool.